# How to redirect to previous page using own back button?

Tags: angularjs

I am using `ng-routing` in application in angularjs. I have my own back button. I want to go back to previous page from where I have redirected to this page? Kindly help me?

Comment: Refer the following link : 
1)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409803/browser-back-button-redirecting-to-previous-page-and-appending-the-route-to-url 

2)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175429/angularjs-getting-previous-route-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `history.back()` on click of your back button. this will redirect to your previous page using browser's history.

Answer (score 1):

A simple directive for that

```
app.directive('historyBackward', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                $window.history.back();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

In your HTML

`<button history-backward>back</button>`